# cout is showing a differnet kind of behavior

Tags: c++, blockchain

I am implementing basics of blockchain. But facing a strange problem. when I run my code after commenting out std::cout statements in main() function, it runs fine. But with those cout statements it is giving wrong output and I really confused why it is happening.
take a look at the whole file. https://github.com/mrcreamio/ourcoin

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>
#include "sha256.h"
using namespace std;
string timestamp();

struct Block{
    string data;
    string prev_hashKey;
    string hashKey;
    int BlockNum;
    Block* next;
    Block* prev;
    long long nonce;

};

class chain{
public:
    Block* GenesisBlock = NULL;

    void insert(string data)
    {
        data += timestamp();
        //data+= " ";
        int length = data.length();
        Block* NewBlock = new Block;
        Block* pntr = GenesisBlock;
        Block* previous_ptr = GenesisBlock;

        if (GenesisBlock == NULL) {
            NewBlock->hashKey = sha256(data);
            string temp;
            while (!(NewBlock->hashKey[0] == '0' && NewBlock->hashKey[1] == '0' && NewBlock->hashKey[2] == '0' && NewBlock->hashKey[3] == '0'  && NewBlock->hashKey[4] == '0'))
            {
                temp = data;
                NewBlock->nonce += 1;
                std::string s = std::to_string(NewBlock->nonce);
                temp += s;
                std::cout << "data = "<<temp << '\n';
                std::cout << "nonce = "<< NewBlock->nonce << '\n';
                NewBlock->hashKey = sha256(temp);
            }
            std::cout << "nonce = "<< NewBlock->nonce << '\n';
            NewBlock->prev_hashKey="000000000000000000";
            NewBlock->data = data;
            NewBlock->BlockNum = 0;
            NewBlock->next = NULL;
            GenesisBlock = NewBlock;
        }
        else {
            int counter = 0;
            while(pntr != NULL) {
                previous_ptr = pntr;
                pntr = pntr->next;
                counter++;
            }
            previous_ptr->next = NewBlock;
            NewBlock->hashKey = sha256(data);
            string temp;
            while (!(NewBlock->hashKey[0] == '0' && NewBlock->hashKey[1] == '0' && NewBlock->hashKey[2] == '0' && NewBlock->hashKey[3] == '0'&& NewBlock->hashKey[4] == '0'))
            {
                temp = data;
                NewBlock->nonce += 1;
                std::cout << "nonce = "<< NewBlock->nonce << '\n';
                std::string s = std::to_string(NewBlock->nonce);
                temp += s;
                std::cout << "data = "<<temp << '\n';
                NewBlock->hashKey = sha256(temp);
            }
            std::cout << "nonce = "<< NewBlock->nonce << '\n';
            NewBlock->prev_hashKey = previous_ptr->hashKey;

            NewBlock->prev = previous_ptr;
            NewBlock->data = data;
            NewBlock->BlockNum = counter;
            NewBlock->next = NULL;
        }
    }
void print(){
    Block* curr = GenesisBlock;
    if (curr == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"-------------------------------------"<<endl;
            std::cout << "Nothing to print" << '\n';
        cout<<"-------------------------------------"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {

        cout<<"BlockNum:  "<<curr->BlockNum<<endl;
        cout<<"Data:  "<<curr->data<<endl;
        cout<<"Hash Key:  "<<curr->hashKey<<endl;
        cout<<"Previous Hash Key:  "<<curr->prev_hashKey<<endl;
        cout<<"Nonce :"<<curr->nonce<<endl;
        if (curr->next != NULL) {

        do{
            curr = curr->next;
            cout<<"-------------------------------------"<<endl;
            cout<<"BlockNum:  "<<curr->BlockNum<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<"Data:  "<<curr->data<<endl;
            cout<<"Hash Key:  "<<curr->hashKey<<endl;
            cout<<"Previous Hash Key:  "<<curr->prev_hashKey<<endl;
            cout<<"Nonce :"<<curr->nonce<<endl;
            cout<<"-------------------------------------"<<endl;
        }while(curr->next != NULL);
    }
    }
}

};

string timestamp()
{
time_t now = time(0);
char* dt = ctime(&now);
return dt;
}

int main(){
    chain ch;
    int var,x;
    string data;
    //**** these lines are creating problem****;
    // cout<<"-------------------------------------"<<endl;
    // cout<<"---------WELCOME TO OURCOIN----------" <<endl;
    // cout<<"-------------------------------------"<<endl;

    ch.insert("give me 50 ourcoins ");
    ch.insert("give ahmed 50 ourcoins ");
    ch.print();
}
```

Comment: If use of `cout` is effecting seemingly unrelated things, that probably means you have undefined behavior somewhere.

Comment: run it under valgrind

Comment: Tip: Don't manage your memory manually, use standard containers and smart-pointers. `std::list` fits what you do, but why not store it in a `std::deque` or `std::vector` instead and eliminate the navigation-pointers? Next, remove redundancies, dead and vestigal code. Still hard to find?

Comment: Running these locally, I see no evidence that anything changed. Can you be more specific? There's a LOT of output.

Comment: *I am implementing basics of blockchain* -- So is your goal really to implement blockchain, or fight with implementing a linked list?  If it is the former, just use `std::list`, i.e. let the C++ library handle those details, and go on implementing the blockchain aspect of your program.  If it is the latter, let me just say that I have yet to see a beginner implement a linked list class correctly, without bugs, etc. unless they get tons of help from an experienced C++ programmer.  So it's your choice -- use what already works (`std::list`), or keep fighting trying to implement a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem may be that the last line of your set of commented out lines does not have a semicolon at the end of it!

As well, just to note you use the namespace std "using namespace std" at the top of your file, which in programming practice should be avoided since it can create conflict when using another namespace (two namespaces may eventually have conflicting functions)

Instead, just use the scope operator to keep your code specific, like you do in your classes: (ie std::cout << "...."; )

Other than that your code looks good and should run!

Comment: It is mistakenly removed while posting question on stack overflow. If that was a problem compiler would have given syntax error.